# String processing using scanner

Tags: java

Question: Write a method called wordWrap that accepts a Scanner representing an input file as its parameter and outputs each line of the file to the console, word-wrapping all lines that are longer than 60 characters. For example, if a line contains 112 characters, the method should replace it with two lines: one containing the first 60 characters and another containing the final 52 characters. A line containing 217 characters should be wrapped into four lines: three of length 60 and a final line of length 37.

**My code:**

```
public void wordWrap(Scanner input) {

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        String line=input.nextLine();
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(line);
        if(scan.hasNext()){
            superOuter:
            while(line.length()>0){

                for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++){
                    if( i<60 && line.length()>59){
                        System.out.print(line.charAt(i));

                    }
                    //FINISH OFF LINE<=60 characters here

                    else if(line.length()<59){

                        for(int j=0;j<line.length();j++){
                            System.out.print(line.charAt(j));

                        }
                        System.out.println();

                        break superOuter;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println();

                        line=line.substring(i);

                        break ;
                    }


                }

            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

*Problem in the output:*

**Expected output:**

```
Hello
How are you
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
I am fine

Thank you
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog

This line is exactly sixty characters long; how interesting!

Goodbye
```

**Produced Output:**

```
Hello
How are you
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
I am fine

Thank you
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the quick brown 
fox jumps over the lazy dog

This line is exactly sixty characters long; how interesting!This line is exactly sixty characters long; how interesting!This line is exactly sixty characters long; how interesting!...
*** ERROR: excessive output on line 13
```

*Where did i do wrong ????*

Comment: Isn't it easier to loop over the lines of the input (the Scanner), check if it is longer than 60 chars, print the first 60 (or less), take the substring from char 60 to the end, and repeat that until the length is 0?

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` condition (for lines of exactly 60 characters), you are only breaking from the inner `for` loop, whereas you want to break from the outer `while` loop (and, therefore, you end up writing out the same line 60 times).

Use instead `break superOuter` as you have for lines of less than 59 characters.